# Change text in textbox based on value

Tags: tableau-api

Is there a way to change the text in a dashboard based on a value?

At its most basic, I want to be able to plug in the word 'increased' or 'decreased' based on a change from year to year for a report.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the free-floating `Text` object from the same menu as vertical / horizonal containers, Blanks, etc. then you can only use parameters and a few "special" values like Workbook Name.

However, you can use a worksheet as a textbox instead. Just make sure you clear the default formatting (borders, etc.) and put your calculated field that resolves into "increased" / "decreased" on the Text mark. In the same way you can add up or down arrows using `CHR()` function and set custom colours (by creating two calculated fields that resolve into "increased" and "" and "decreased" and "")